# Вопрос отметили к закрытию с оскорбительной формулировкой. Как быть?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Кто автор сего литературного выражения в качестве причины закрытия вопроса? Почему не рассмотрели более "доходчивые" словечки? Зачем превращать базу знаний в притон для "блатных" разработчиков?

**Обновлено**

Изначально подумал, что данная причина была добавлена в качестве стандартной для закрытия, что недопустимо в такой формулировке, потому и задал данный вопрос. Но, как разъяснил @Nofate, это лишь формулировка одного из участников, который дописал причину в такой форме сам.

Отсюда такой вопрос: как на это смотрит сообщество? Ведь в качестве причины для закрытия можно написать словечки и пожестче, а их потом читать всем потенциальным пользователям данного сайта, когда они наткнуться на закрытый вопрос.

> [image: Другие причины закрытия]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обратите внимание: последний пункт в списке причин закрытия предполагает ввод своей причины. После этого пользовательская причина закрытия добавляется к списку возможных причин закрытия этого вопроса. Т.е. это не часть утвержденного списка стандартных причин, а сообщение одного из участников. Нет смысла обсуждать его тут, на Мете - достаточно тревоги на соответствующем сообщении под вопросом.

---

Теперь по поводу содержания. Слово "шлак" не имеет никакого отношения к блатному жаргону и существовало задолго до него. Это слово используется в металлургии (шлак - побочный продукт в домнах) , "альтернативной" медицине (вспомните про "шлаки в организме"). Это слово является синонимом слову "мусор" (кроме металлургии, где шлакам однажды внезапно нашлось применение).

Comment: @Nofate уже указал на это, я обновил вопрос. А что касается тревоги на закрытый вопрос, модераторы смогут определить, кто является автором причины для закрытия?

Comment: @edem каждая такая причина сначала существует в виде комментария. А модераторы могут видеть удалённые комментарии, и их авторов тоже. Так что...

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, вариант, с которым вы столкнулись, не самый плохой, бывало и похуже. Конечно, такие комментарии не допустимы и нарушают принцип "Будьте вежливы", который принят тут на сайте.

Даже к авторам вопросов, не соответствующих тематике, нужно относится с уважением, не пытаться их как-то унизить. Иначе подобное нежелательное поведение участников с высокой репутацией будет отпугивать новичков.

А последовательность действий

1. проголосовать за закрытие с расширенной причиной
2. удалить автоматический комментарий

считаю некрасивой. Мол, на тебе, сейчас закрою твой вопрос, будешь знать как ошибаться!

И не думайте, что такую реплику в причине закрытия видят только голосующие*. В некоторых случаях его могут увидеть автор вопроса, первый комментатор (если был), случайные посетители, у которых в это время была открыта страница с вопросом. Более того, такой комментарий может прийти в уведомлении по электронной почте, где уже так просто удалить его не получится.

<sub>* после закрытия вопроса по расширенной причине на жёлтой плашке комментария уже не будет</sub>

Comment: Согласен, что бывают и хуже, сталкивался. Мне ваш вариант ответа кажется более общим и подходящим для галки, чем ранее данный единственный ответ.